# Spring boot application.properties extends another property file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have few properties in one property file which I want to inherit to application properties. Please let know if that is possible in spring boot.

something like

```
application.properties
----------------------
extends = otherproperty.properties
property1 = value1
property2= value2
property3 = value3

otherproperty.properties
------------------------
property4=value4
property5 = value5
```

When the spring boot app loads, I want all 5 properties should be loaded and available using @Value annotation. The spring boot automatically picks the application.properties in classpath and I don't have applicaitoncontext xml or any property loader code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to *inherit* one property file in another, or do you want to *merge* them? In other words, can both property files contain property `property6`, or do they not overlap?

Comment: I just want to inherit, they don't overlap.

Comment: What happens if the properties overlap? does property value in application.properties get overwritten by other property.properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question and found a good explained solution by *mkyong*. The tutorial explains how you can use different extending Spring profiles by using `.porperties` or `.yaml` files. (Same approach like [eSala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2597143/esala) mentioned.)

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-profile-based-properties-and-yaml-example/

Answer (score 14):

You can use **Profiles** for that.

With `application.properties` files, you can define a file for every `Profile`, like this:

```
application.properties # This is the main file
spring.profiles=p1,p2,p3
prop-main=hi

application-p1.properties # This is the file with p1 properties
property1=patata

application-p2.properties # This is the file with p2 properties
property2=catsup

application-p3.properties # This is the file with p3 properties
property3=helloworld
```

Spring will translate the files and use it like this:

```
application.properties # This is the main file
spring.profiles=p1,p2,p3
prop-main=hi
property1=patata
property2=catsup
property3=helloworld
```

This solution works, but you have to keep a separate file for each group.

There is another way, you can use a single `YAML` file instead of multiple `properties` files. Just replace the `application.properties` with an `application.yml` and do something like this:

```
server:
    address: 192.168.1.100
---
spring:
    profiles: development
server:
    address: 127.0.0.1
---
spring:
    profiles: production
server:
    address: 192.168.1.120
```

You can read the reference documentation for more info about [Using YAML instead of Properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml) and about [Multi-profile YAML documents](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-multi-profile-yaml).

Answer (score 11):

For me works `spring.profiles.include=p1,p2,p3` in `application.properties` file

Comment: Will spring.profiles.include work in application-dev.properties as well?
Suppose I have two dev environments
dev1 and dev2 which have many common properties.
I want to have one devbase.properties which I want to include in dev1 and dev2

Is this possible?