# How to use properties in a custom configuration file in the application.properties？

Tags: java, spring-boot

My project has two properties file,apllication.properties and emailConfig.properties.How to write in application.properties to use another files properties(I don`t want to use annottation in any Class)

```
spring.mail.username=${email.163.username}
spring.mail.password=${email.163.password}
```

But I must use @PropertySource(value = "emailConfig.properties") in SpringBootApplication class,otherwise the code can`t reslove the spring.email.username.
What should I write in application.properties without use annotation

Comment: why you don't want to use any annotations?

Comment: One properties file can't include another.  Why not just put them all the properties the same file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot application.properties extends another property file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263316/spring-boot-application-properties-extends-another-property-file)